# Return a collection from MongoDB collection if query matches

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, discord

Im trying to make a command where if the query matches that is 'characterName' matches 'msgArgs1', then i want to return the other values of the document which matches but it gives me error like 'characterID' is undefined

MY CODE:

````
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://Owner:@cluster0-umjcr.mongodb.net/Justice_Bot?retryWrites=true&w=majority',{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const Character = require("../models/character");

module.exports.run = async(client, message, cmdArgs, argss) => {
    let msgArgs1 = argss.slice(1).join(" ");

         let p = Character.findOne({
             characterName: msgArgs1
         }, (characterID, characterName, originalName, type, link, Intelligence, Strength, Speed, Durability , Power ,Combat) => {

               if (p) {
                    let info = new MessageEmbed()
                       .setDescription(`**#${characterID.characterID} ${JSON.stringify.characterName}**`)
                       .setDescription(`Name: ${JSON.stringify.originalName} Type: ${type}`)
                       .addField('Intelligence: ', Intelligence.Intelligence, true)
                       .addField('Strength: ', Strength.Strength, true )
                       .addField('Speed: ', Speed.Speed, true)
                       .addField('Durability: ', Durability.Durability, true)
                       .addField('Power: ', Power.Power, true)
                       .addField('Combat: ', Combat.Combat, true)
                       .setImage(JSON.stringify.link, true)
                       .setColor(0xE3C910)
                    message.channel.send(info);   
                }else return message.channel.send("character Not found!")
            })
}```
````

Comment: Could you show us what your `character` model file looks like ?